# how to insert an image in miktex generated document

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I am doing following

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{gd.jpg}
    \caption{Amazon Guard Duty}
\end{figure}
```

and in the preamble I have following

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{C:\Users\user1\user\Lab assignments\project\march2020\paper\EUSFLAT 2019 template\images}
```

the path "C:\Users\user1\user\Lab assignments\project\march2020\paper\EUSFLAT 2019 template\images"
is the folder path to images which I have embedded in the generated pdf.

but when I compile this then I get

```
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{gd.jpg}
```

so what mistake I am doing in above?

*update1*
as suggested in below comments  I changed the `\` in the file path to `/`
so new path is as following

```
\documentclass{eusflat2019}
\title{\bf paper title}
\author{{\bf author1$^1$} , {\bf author1$^2$} , {\bf author1$^{3}$}\\
$^1$CSE  \\ $^2$CSE \\$^3$ CSE }
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{C:/Users/User1/user/Lab assignments/project/march2020/paper/EUSFLAT 2019 template/images}
```

and in the brackets I did

\includegraphics{{gd.jpg}}

now what I get is

Package pdftex.def Error: File `gd.jpg' not found: using draft setting. \includegraphics{{gd.jpg}}

I tried

\includegraphics{{gd.jpg}}

then the error I get is

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `gd.jpg' not found: using draft setting. \includegraphics{gd.jpg}
```

I am using tex studio on Windows 10.

Comment: you probably don't need graphicspath if that is where the paper is but if you do use it use `/` not `\ ` and an extra set of braces `\graphicspath {{c:/aaa/bbb/}}`  note the format you show is not a tex error the undefined command would be shown as `\Users`

Comment: if you are using texstudio you could try asking again at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I am using texstudio I will finally upload all this in overleaf once I am finished with doing all this. So in overleaf also will I have to do new adjustments

Comment: so avoid putting  machine specific paths like c:users... at all you only need a path relative to where you run latex (usually the folder with your main document). It is depressing that after all these years I can still recognise an editor by the way it confuses users by mangling error messages.